# Dual boot Ubuntu 18.04.3 alongside windows 10, windows bootup stucks on purple screen

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS alongside windows 10. Ubuntu is working fine but when I bootup windows from grub 2.02 it stucks on purple screen. My BIOS mode is legacy and the system is hp probook 450 g3. 
I have tried boot-repair. The report is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FQHT8rWSpf/) but the problem remains still.

Answer (score 0):

Any idea of what your GPU is?  Is is an Intel or AMD based laptop?  I was looking into a similar problem on my Ryzen mobile laptop.  I know there is a kernal bug on Ryzen mobile laptops as well as laptops with AMD discrete GPUs with this issue.

Comment: Its Intel(R) SKL Mobile/Destop

Comment: Oh sorry you asked for GPU. Its AMD Radeon R7 M340.

Comment: Here is the kernel bug I mentioned, I am not sure it is the same issue, but it is something you may want to look at. The current work around it kinda on the technical side.  https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203431#a0